# Calling NSURLConnection one by one

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I have a NSMutableArray containing 10 URLs from which I need to grab the HTTP headers.

Below is my code:

```
for(int i=0; i<[contactsArray count];i++)
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    NSString *reqstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",urlString ];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:reqstr]]; 
    NSLog(@"requested url is %@",reqstr);

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[mDict JSONData]];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request         delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

}
```

**current** **result**: all requests are going to server at a time.

**expected result**: want to send one request to sever after getting response I want to send another request in background.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wait for the response to arrive before sending the next request.

Comment: Why don't you use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refactor your code to use the `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` method, and call itself once the current post is complete:

Move your count to an instance variable. Let's call it currentItem. Your code might look something like this:

```
- (void) postItems;
{
  while (currentItem < [contactsArray count)
  {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    NSString *reqstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",urlString ];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:reqstr]]; 
    NSLog(@"requested url is %@",reqstr);

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[mDict JSONData]];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: request 
      queue:  dispatch_get_main_queue ()
      completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
      {
        //check for errors
        //save any response data

        //Now trigger the next request
        currentItem++
        [self postItems];
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

(The syntax for the completion block might not be exactly right. I struggle a little with the syntax for blocks that take parameters.)

Answer (score 0):

You use ASIHTTPRequest asynchronous call:

[Link for ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

Then write  like following code:

```
for(int i=0; i<[contactsArray count];i++)
{

NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
__block ASIHTTPRequest* request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setCompletionBlock:^
 {

              //NEED SOMEHOW RETURN TRUE IF SUCESSED

 }];

[request setFailedBlock:^
 {
     //NEED RETURN FALSE
 }];

[request startAsynchronous];

}
```

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest is deprecated,  use AFNetworking instead.

Comment: For my projects i am using ASIHTTPRequest. its working fine. only ARC is not available in  ASIHTTPRequest.

Comment: Yes it is working fine but you should always try to use latest libraries which are maintained.

Comment: I agree with @JanakNirmal. ASIHTTPRequest is no longer supported, and developing new projects using it would be a mistake since it is getting more and more out of date.

Comment: Besides, this is a simple enough project that it only requires a few lines of code to solve it without any third party libraries. See my answer.